# Rails application to standalone package including gem dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, package

Is it possible to make a package (like a Heroku slug) of a Rails application including all the gem dependencies?

Then copy the package to a remote server, enter its directory and execute 'bundle exec rails s', 'bundle exec sidekiq' or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's that easy, but you can use `bundle package` to get all your gem files in one place for easy install later...

```
bundle package(1) bundle-package.1.html
      Package the .gem files required by  your  application  into  the
      vendor/cache directory
```

There's an option to bundle install to use those vendor'd gems.  It escapes me at the moment, but the docs should turn it up.

Comment: Maybe you mean 'bundle install --deployment' ?